# How to make a simple grafical interface in C# for DCRAW

Tags: c#, user-interface, interpolation, dcraw

i have a problem. I need to make a simple GUI in Visual Studio 2008 using C Sharp that uses a Dave Coffins DCRAW written in C but I don't know how to "connect" dcraw.c (DCRAW source code) file with Csharp... UFRAW is the example of grafical interface that uses dcraw but I can't find it's source code. My application should be very simple: to recognize raw file on digital camera or any disc and uses one interpolatio algorithm on that raw file.

Answer (score 1):

you must compile the c code into a dll. this dll can be used through pinvoke from c#

you could also make a managed c++ project and convert the c code into native c++ code. in managed c++ there is a very easy way to access the native code.